# IIF statement on a criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a query with fields named "FirstName", "Condition", "Status". The Condition field can be "Working" or "Under Maintenance" or "Damaged" and for Status, it's "Available" or "Unavailable" or "Assigned".

If Condition is set to "Under Maintenance" then Status should switch to "Unavailable". The same goes if Condition is set to "Damaged". However, if FirstName is populated then Condition must switch to "Working" and Status should also be set to "Assigned"

The code below is only my guess and I know it will not work.

`Status: IIf(IsNull([FirstName],"Available","Unavailable","Assigned" and [Condition]=Damaged),"Unavailable","Available")`

Comment: And how would Condition be set to "Under Maintenance" or "Damaged"? Are these 3 fields in table and populated with user input via form? Sounds like you really need to do data validation with VBA.

Comment: It will be populated using a form and a combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this criteria? The criteria is querying the status but does not change it.

You are dealing with a succession of states that change over time and you must set two different states. What you are describing a [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) whose state changes at specific events. I.e. you must execute some code which changes existing entries. something like this:

```
Private Sub Condition_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Me!Condition
        Case "Working"
            Me!Status = "Assigned"
        Case "Under Maintenance"
            Me!Status = "Unavailable"
        Case "Damaged"
            Me!Status = "Unavailable"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub FirstName_AfterUpdate()
    If Nz(FirstName) <> "" Then
        Me!Condition = "Working"
        Me!Status = "Assigned"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @olivier Jacot-Descombers for the response, I will check your solution tomorrow when I reach in the office.

Comment: Probably need to include in `Condition_AfterUpdate` a check on FirstName value, in case user mistakenly tries to change Condition after FirstName is populated. Could also have ConditionalFormatting disable Condition and Status comboboxes if FirstName has value.

Comment: And if there is a Status combobox, probably need validation code in its AfterUpdate event as well to make sure its user input is compatible with the other inputs.

Comment: Yes. The problem description seems to be incomplete.